# How to translate svg element along y-axis?

Tags: d3.js

I have a svg element which is moving along a path, and when you click on it (onclick) it has to "fall down", so I would like to translate it along y-axis,keeping the same x-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Once you didn't provide any code, this will be a "generic" answer:

```
yourElement.on("click", function(){
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0, " + someValue + ")");
});
```